# Circular loading bar with image

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to create an achievement system in my game. I want players to see their % achievement progress like this.

For example, if he completed 65% -> 75% -> 100% to look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP2MX.jpg

Is there any way to crop the image circular to look like a circular progess bar? A direction, a hint, a pod or a piece of code is appreciated.

My images will be rectangles with rounded corners and the code is written in SpriteKit.

Comment: You can add a white circle on the image and set the opposite percentage on it.

Comment: This can do as a workaround if I don't find an easier solution. I can create a circle with Path and add it as a mask to crop image.

Comment: Why do you think of it as a workaround? This is exactly what is needed - masking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. Indeed the best and easiest solution was to create a mask_node.

```
    let button_image : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    let crop_node : SKCropNode = SKCropNode()

    let completion : CGFloat = 0.83  // from 0.0 to 1.0

    let circle_bezier_path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: 200, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2 * completion, clockwise: true)
    circle_bezier_path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    let mask_node : SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: circle_bezier_path.cgPath)
    mask_node.zRotation = CGFloat.pi/2

    let wrapper_node = SKNode()
    wrapper_node.addChild(mask_node)

    crop_node.maskNode = wrapper_node
    crop_node.addChild(button_image)
    addChild(crop_node)
```

Good luck!